# Generic Graph Lib in Delphi, Speed of ObjectList

Tags: c++, algorithm, delphi, graph

we are developing an generic graph library using DELPHI XE7.  The target graph size is ~ 1 MIO vertex nodes and  ~ 10 MIO edges in that graph.  The current state of our progress is a basic implementation of TGraph class  and some basic graph algorithm!.

The question goes in the speed on inserting data to the vertex and edgelist with has been implemented as an TObjectList . I can only put here some  fragmental code, but it might help to get the relevant points of my question

```
  TGraph<Tdata> = Class
  private
    /// <summary>
    /// TVertexList<Tdata>;
    /// </summary>
    _vertices: TObjectList<TVertex<Tdata>>;
    /// <summary>
    /// TEdgesList<TData>;
    /// </summary>
    _edges: TObjectList<TEdge<Tdata>>;

    .....
    end;


function TGraph<Tdata>.addVertex(u: TVertex<Tdata>): Integer;
var
  u_index: Integer;
begin


  if (not _vertices.Contains(u)) then
  begin
    u_index := _vertices.Count;
    u.vertex_index := u_index;
    Result := _vertices.Add(u);
  end;

end;

procedure TGraph<Tdata>.addEdge(e: TEdge<Tdata>;
  checkDuplicates: Boolean = true);
var
  i, j: Integer;
begin

  if (checkDuplicates) then
    if (self._edges.Contains(e)) then  exit;


  ///  normal add egde stuff 
  ....


end;
```

As shown in the code we use the TList contains function to check wheather certain elements already exist in the graph. Speed analysis shows that the algorithm has a complexity of n2 which is fatal for us.

The questions goes now like that

- a)   is speed of list.contains(...) performance in Delphi really n² ?

  b)   Any better function to check wheather an element exists or not?

  c)   Instead of generic Object List can we change to any other more
  faster data type for building generic graphs?

  d)   I know C++ Boost
  or METIS/HMETIS Graph libs, but I can#t not write on a short
  timeframe evaluation programs for these lib. Do they also suffer that
  N² problem on building large graphs?

[image: drawing]

[image]

this graph shows **checkDuplicates =  false** as green curve and **checkDuplicates =  true** condition as red curve for addegde...) .

Comment: Have you tried TDictonary

Comment: This isn't really a Delphi question. You are asking about the perf characteristics of random access arrays. How do think Contains is implemented? It's a linear search. O(n).

Comment: So, if performance is important to you then you need to think very hard about the design, up front. Writing code whose performance characteristics you cannot predict won't end well. You need to back up and learn some theory. Start by reading a good algorithms text book. Study the code of respected libraries. Expect them to be written in C++. Learn to understand that language. Learn how to write efficient delphi code when you code in Delphi. Avoiding heap allocation is usually a good move.

Comment: If you sort your list you can do BinarySearch on your items instead of the SweepSearch

Comment: @JensBorrisholt Sorting is not free.

Comment: Correct! Butit might pay off.

Comment: @JensBorrisholt Not likely. O(1) search beats O(log n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is `TObjectList<T>.Contains()` really O(n<sup>2</sup>)?

No, it is O(n). The implementation of `Contains()` is simply a linear search. The graph you show is not linear, but then we don't know how you generated it. Presumably your code doesn't test purely the performance of `Contains()`.

My guess is that you are measuring the population of your list. For your code that will be O(n<sup>2</sup>). Loosely speaking, adding items is O(n), and checking if they are in the list is also O(n) due to your choice of container, i.e. that you have to perform linear search on each add to the list. So put that together and you have O(n<sup>2</sup>) performance.

> Any better function to check whether an element exists or not?

Not if your data is held in this type of container. A `TObjectList<T>` is a random access array in performance terms. You would need to choose a different container if you wanted better than `O(n)` search performance. For instance a `TDictionary<K,V>` would give you `O(1)` search performance.

> Instead of `TObjectList<T>` can we change to any other more faster data type for building generic graphs?

See above.

> I know C++ Boost or METIS/HMETIS Graph libs, but I can't write on a short timeframe evaluation programs for these lib. Do they also suffer that O(n<sup>2</sup>) problem on building large graphs?

I don't know. As I said, we don't know where your graph comes from so we can't actually tell what you are measuring. However, any decent library in this field is surely not going to perform a full linear search over all edges before adding a new one.

Comment: I added real measurement results and change of addedge call is clearly O(n2)  and this is due to execution of List.contains(..);

Comment: Contains is `O(n)`. It is linear search.

Comment: We still can't be sure what you are measuring but we can guess. For case n you add n edges. So, n times you call add. Let i represent each step. i loops from 1 to n. When you call Add you need to check for dupes. That costs i comparisons. So you do 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n comparisons. That is n(n+1)/2 comparisons. A call to Contains is O(n). But you make n calls to Contains. That what I say in the answer. Write a simple program to instrument Contains and count the comparisons. It will help you understand.